# DateDifference in C#

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-project

Using VBA for MS Project, one of the command is DateDifference.

```
differencedate = Application.DateDifference(tsk.BaselineStart, tsk.BaselineFinish, ActiveProject.Calendar)
```

However, I am trying to use VSTO for MS Project, but I can figure out how to use DateDifference. Is there an equivalent command cor C#?

Comment: Subtracting two DateTime objects in C# gives a TimeSpan, which includes the difference in days, hours, minutes, etc. Can you give code of the values you are reading out of the file? What type is tsk.BaseLineStart/Finish?

Comment: tsk.BaseLineStart/Finish are dates, the command Application.DateDifference on VBA is very specific for MSProject usage.

tsk.BaselineStart>>>>  28/04/14 8:00:00 AM
tsv.StartDate>>>> 28/04/14

Comment: When you use them in C# are they DateTime objects, or are they some office interop type specific to MS Project?

Comment: office interop type, I use System.Convert.ToDateTime() to be sure they are DateTime type before using them

Comment: Then its just Timespan timeDiff = Convert.ToDateTime(tsk.BaseLineStart) - Convert.ToDateTime(tsk.BaseLineFinish)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864591.aspx, the only example of DateDifference is in VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same exact MS Project VBA method in vsto. Change `Application` to your MSProject.Application variable name and preface `ActiveProject` with that variable. For example, if your variable name is `ProjApp` use this:

```
differencedate = ProjApp.DateDifference(tsk.BaselineStart, tsk.BaselineFinish, ProjApp.ActiveProject.Calendar)
```

The returned value will be the duration in minutes between the dates, the same as when you use it in VBA.

**Bottom line**: If you want the same calculation as you get in VBA, use this method. If you want the elapsed time between the dates use C#'s built-in date math functions. The former is most relevant when dealing with MS Project dates that are [cpm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_path_method)-driven.

**Update**:  I tested this in C# and found that the `DateDifference` method throws a `NotImplemented` exception (but works fine in vb.net). Since this method is the only way to accurately calculate the duration between two dates, you can use vb.net for just this part adding a separate (vb) project within your solution.

**Update 2**: Here is a vb.net class you can call from c#:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class MsProjectMethods

    Public Function MsProjectDateDifference(ByVal ProjApp As MSProject.Application,
                                            ByVal startDate As DateTime,
                                            ByVal finishDate As DateTime) As Int32
        Dim returnValue As Object = ProjApp.DateDifference(startDate, finishDate)
        If IsNumeric(returnValue) Then
            Return Convert.ToInt32(returnValue)
        Else
            Throw New System.Exception("An exception has occurred.")
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

And here's how you can call it:

```
ClassLibrary1.MsProjectMethods MspVb = new ClassLibrary1.MsProjectMethods();
            int differencedate = MspVb.MsProjectDateDifference(ProjApp,
                Convert.ToDateTime(tsk.BaselineStart),
                Convert.ToDateTime(tsk.BaselineFinish));
```

Comment: Hi rachel, I was able to use the code without error but I am not getting any result.

differencedate = mspApp.DateDifference(System.Convert.ToDateTime(task.BaselineStart), System.Convert.ToDateTime(tsv.StartDate).AddDays(7), mspApp.ActiveProject.Calendar);

I am using C#, any difference? thanks.

Comment: Don't convert the task dates, just pass them as-is. Try that without adding 7 days to the start, just to get it working, then tackle adding 7 days.

Comment: yup, I already did, i made different solutions, basically what I have now is this: differencedate = (mspApp.DateDifference(task.BaselineStart, tsv.StartDate, mspApp.ActiveProject.Calendar)) / 60; still no result... i have a messagebox after this line displaying the differencedate

Comment: @GilbertAllanWong I added some sample code to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Dates are stored as number with the number of days from Jan 1, 1900 being the integer part of the number and fraction part of the number being a fraction of a day.  When the number is display it can vary depending on the method you use for the conversion to a string.  Both VBA and Net Library store the number the same in memory.  Some methods will display just the whole number, some with display only the fractional part of the number, and other methods will display the entire number.  Also display can vary by country. 6.16 could be 6 days, 6 hours, 6 minutes, or 6 seconds.  It could be the entire number, just the fractional part of the number or even smaller part of the fraction.  Math is perform by simply adding or subtracting the number stored in memory. Hopefully aligned properly.

Comment: Hi, Yes I am aware of how dates are stored in memory. However datediff is different from datedifference. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864591.aspx, if they are the same, it must have stated both can be used interchangebly. And DateDifference is specifically created for VBA MSProject only.

Answer (score -1):

Timespan has the following methods

```
        //     Gets the days component of the time interval represented by the current System.TimeSpan
        //     structure.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The day component of this instance. The return value can be positive or negative.
        public int Days { get; }


        // Summary:
        //     Gets the hours component of the time interval represented by the current
        //     System.TimeSpan structure.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The hour component of the current System.TimeSpan structure. The return value
        //     ranges from -23 through 23.
        public int Hours { get; }


        // Summary:
        //     Gets the milliseconds component of the time interval represented by the current
        //     System.TimeSpan structure.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The millisecond component of the current System.TimeSpan structure. The return
        //     value ranges from -999 through 999.
        public int Milliseconds { get; }


        // Summary:
        //     Gets the minutes component of the time interval represented by the current
        //     System.TimeSpan structure.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The minute component of the current System.TimeSpan structure. The return
        //     value ranges from -59 through 59.
        public int Minutes { get; }


        // Summary:
        //     Gets the seconds component of the time interval represented by the current
        //     System.TimeSpan structure.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The second component of the current System.TimeSpan structure. The return
        //     value ranges from -59 through 59.
        public int Seconds { get; }


        // Summary:
        //     Gets the number of ticks that represent the value of the current System.TimeSpan
        //     structure.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The number of ticks contained in this instance.
        public long Ticks { get; }


        // Summary:
        //     Gets the value of the current System.TimeSpan structure expressed in whole
        //     and fractional days.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The total number of days represented by this instance.
        public double TotalDays { get; }


        // Summary:
        //     Gets the value of the current System.TimeSpan structure expressed in whole
        //     and fractional hours.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The total number of hours represented by this instance.
        public double TotalHours { get; }


        // Summary:
        //     Gets the value of the current System.TimeSpan structure expressed in whole
        //     and fractional milliseconds.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The total number of milliseconds represented by this instance.
        public double TotalMilliseconds { get; }


        // Summary:
        //     Gets the value of the current System.TimeSpan structure expressed in whole
        //     and fractional minutes.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The total number of minutes represented by this instance.
        public double TotalMinutes { get; }


        // Summary:
        //     Gets the value of the current System.TimeSpan structure expressed in whole
        //     and fractional seconds.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The total number of seconds represented by this instance.
        public double TotalSeconds { get; }​
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just have a followup question. using datedifference, and these parameters, tsk.BaselineStart>>28/04/14 8:00:00 AM, tsv.StartDate + 7>>>05/05/14, the answer is 2400, if I just subtract the dates the answer is 6.16:00:00... how was 2400 computed? i think Datedifference is not just subtracting dates.

Comment: the two functions are the same except the parameters are slightly different.  To get minutes DateDiff(startDate, EndDate).Minute or DateDifference(StartDate, FinishDate, Minute)

Comment: no it's not, the last parameter of DateDifference is calendar, and it returns the duration between two dates in minutes, for an automatically scheduled task. Not just subtracting dates. the problem is, it is for VBA only.